# Como pegar o nome de um arquivo

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um formulário e quero pegar o nome dele.
Eu já utilizei o filereader, tentei utiliza-lo mas não consegui.
Eu fiz de um jeito que mostra os dados do arquivo em um array, porém não sei como pegar o nome desse array

```
<script>
    const fileSelector = document.getElementById('images');
    fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const fileList = event.target.files;
        console.log(fileList);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `files` de um `<input>` do tipo `file` retorna uma [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), que é um objeto similar a um array. É, pois, uma lista de arquivos (instâncias de [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)).

Para obter o nome do arquivo de um objeto `File`, você pode utilizar a propriedade `name`. Para saber as outras propriedades consulte a documentação.

Um exemplo:

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#field');

field.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  for (const file of field.files) {
    console.log(file.name);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="field" />
```

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito.